# Scores API: Deleting all app scores not working despite "true" returned

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to clear my Facebook scoreboard every day for a daily challenge.

When I make a DELETE request to http://graph.facebook.com/myAppID/ with the APP ACCESS TOKEN get a value of "true" back which would tell me that it succeeded.

However, if I follow that up (even a few minutes later) with a GET request to http://graph.facebook.com/myAppID/ with the USER ACCESS TOKEN  I am still seeing plenty of scores for that user and their friends.

My understanding is that this shouldn't be the case - issuing a delete request should wipe them all out.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's just a typo in your question, but to delete *all* the scores for the app, you need to make the DELETE request to `/APP_ID/scores`, not to `/APP_ID/` (FROM https://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/ )